# Microsoft Access - Form that updates total fields for a given date

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I am trying to create a form for the purpose of track/ing shipments. Of primary interest are the number of samples shipped, and the number of rice bags shipped. The user has asked for a couple fields in the form that show the total numbers of each for the given date. There are typically 6 or so records for a given date.

I currently have a select query that produces these totals, grouped by date. I cannot seem to get the right combination of events or buttons to  work. I have experimented with various form events as well.

In summation, I want a field in a form that keeps a running total of samples for the given date. The problem I keep encountering is this seems to invariably end up populated with the first date it encounters in the table. For example, 19/11/12 has 388 samples, and this ends up in the Total Samples field for all records in the form.

Example:

```
 Private Sub Samples_AfterUpdate()
    Forms![2013_Assay_Tracking]![Total Samples] = DLookup("[Total_Samples]", "Assay Tracking Totals", "Date_Shipped='" & [Forms]![2013_Assay_Tracking]![Date_Shipped] & "'")
End Sub
```

This works, but populates the form with the total number of samples for the first date shipped. There are currently 4 different dates.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If date shipped is a date, use #, in addition, it seems you may need DSum:

```
Private Sub Samples_AfterUpdate()
    Forms![2013_Assay_Tracking]![Total Samples] = _
       DSum("[Total_Samples]", "Assay Tracking Totals", "Date_Shipped=#" _
       & [Forms]![2013_Assay_Tracking]![Date_Shipped] & "#")
End Sub
```

You can simplify problems with locale by putting the form reference within the quotes:

```
DSum("[Total_Samples]", "Assay Tracking Totals", _
        "Date_Shipped=[Forms]![2013_Assay_Tracking]![Date_Shipped]")
```

Finally, it seems from the above that you are using a continuous form, so a reference to the form will only include the current record. If this is the case, you may wish to set a textbox to:

```
=DSum("[Total_Samples]","Assay Tracking Totals","Date_Shipped=#" & [Date_Shipped] & "#")
```